# DropDownList Attribute not working on mouseout

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, attributes

I have a dropdownlist in a template field of a gridview. I am tryin to change the width of the dropdownlist is display all the values when I mouse over and then change the width back when you mouse out. Here is the code:

```
 ddl.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "event.srcElement.style,width = '186px';")
 ddl.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "event.srcElement.style.width = '';")
```

I works great when I mouse over but the mouse out doesn't change in back? am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a comma where a dot should be between style and width:

```
ddl.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "event.srcElement.style,width = '186px';");
```

should be

```
ddl.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "event.srcElement.style.width = '186px';");
```

And it probably wouldn't hurt to add semi-colons to the end of your statements.

Comment: No problem. It happens to all of us.